# Autotools way to handle local vs installed data file

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

Suppose a program `<somepath>/src/program.c` which is supposed to read data from `<somepath>/data/datafile` during runtime. If `Makefile.am` passes `AM_CPPFLAGS=-DDATADIR=\"@datarootdir@\"` during build, the installed binary can successfully find the data file in `/usr/local/share`. So far so good. Question is, what's the Autotools way instrumente the source code so that the installed binary reads form `datarootdir`, but the local, uninstalled binary reads from (project-local, not system) `<somepath>/data/datafile`?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an Autotools way to do this specifically — it depends on your specific situation. Common solutions are, for example, to first look for the data files in a relative path to the location of your built binary, or to have a `UNINSTALLED_PATH` environment variable that overrides the installed path where it looks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Actually, the program currently resorts to the first strategy, but I can't figure out a reliable, portable way to achieve this, seeing that the binary may be called from outside its location. As an ad hoc measure I can either use some argv[0] heuristic, which is unreliable, or read from /proc/<pid>, which is not portable. It seems a long-standing problem that one of a POSIX way to determine the process's binary path. It seems that the environment variable ideia is more promising.

Answer (score 1):

> what's the Autotools way instrumente the source code so that the
> installed binary reads form `datarootdir`, but the local, uninstalled
> binary reads from (project-local, not system)
> `<somepath>/data/datafile`?

How do you suppose the program is going to recognize at runtime whether it has been installed?  For a program compiled from C sources, installation just means copying the executable into its destination directory (`<prefix>/bin` by default).  It's the same program, and there is no foolproof way for it to determine whether it was loaded from the intended installation directory.<sup>*</sup>

In any event, the Autotools are tools for creating build systems.  They have some useful features around testing uninstalled programs, but nothing specific to this.

A pretty common way to approach the issue is to provide a way to *tell* the program explicitly which directory to use (or which config file to use, or which *etc* to use).  Even if the primary motivation is to support build-time testing, the ability to do this is of some general use.  Among the better ways to support such a thing are

- command-line option
- environment variable
- runtime configuration directive (if your program reads a config file at runtime)
- input data (if you have the flexibility to make your input format support this)

Those are not mutually exclusive, though implementing all of them would surely be overkill.  Some of them are amenable to use via a wrapper script, which can disguise the details from ordinary users.  You'll have to decide the specifics that make sense for your case, but for good flexibility without going overboard, I would probably do something like the following: the program uses the first applicable one of ...

1. Command-line option
2. (maybe) input data
3. (maybe) environment variable OR configuration file
4. Compiled in default based on `datarootdir`

If you choose to write a wrapper script, then perhaps it determines its own location and specifies a data directory relative to that using one of the above. I urge you, however, not to attempt automagical detection of whether the program has been installed as a means to choose what directories to use at runtime.

---

<sup>*</sup>I mean that pretty literally.  There are approaches that will catch most cases, but as far as I can see, none that cannot be fooled.

Comment: You got straight to the point: "build-time test" (I should have worded that myself).  Indeed, runtime detection of binary path is not the sought after workaround. I was considering something in the line of the wrapper script, inspired in libtool's strategy (test script, install binary). But yes, it's overkill in this case. Thank you ver much for the detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

To put it shortly, the original question was about conventional ways to implement build-time test of a program which, during build, should read data files from a path in the project tree (say, ~/home/bar), and when installed, should read from the the default system's data path (say, /usr/share).

From the suggested approaches and further research, the implemented solution may be summarized as follows.

`Makefile.am`:

```
in_PROGRAMS = foo.bin 

foo_bin_SOURCES = main.c 
    
bin_SCRIPTS = foo

foo: foo.sh
        cp $< $@

clean-local:
        rm -f foo

install-exec-hook: 
        cd $(DESTDIR)/$(bindir) && mv foo.bin foo

uninstall-hook:
        rm -f $(DESTDIR)/$(bindir)/foo

EXTRA_DIST = foo.sh
```

When the software is built, a helper shell script `foo` is created (out of a the template `foo.sh`) which evokes the real binary `foo.bin` with appropriate command line parameters to load data from the project tree.

`foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

ARG="$0"
PROGRAM="$(dirname $ARG)/foo.bin"

if [ -f "$PROGRAM" ]; then
    if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
        ./$PROGRAM -data_dir /project/data/path
    else
        ./$PROGRAM "$1"
    fi
else
    echo "Program not found."
    exit 1
fi
```

When the software is installed, an `install-exec-hook` is triggered to rename the binary from `foo.bin` to `foo`. Without further options, it should read data from the system data path.